# How to remove known hosts from Windows 10 SSH?

Tags: windows-10, ssh

I am using Windows 10's built-in ssh client and would like to remove an entry added to the list of known hosts.

Where is this stored?

Comment: Do you mean Windows Subsystem for Linux's ssh client? Windows doesn't have a built in ssh client that I know of unless you mean that one. If thats the one you meant then check the ~/.ssh/known_hosts file for that host

Comment: @KyleH WSL is not enabled on this machine; it's a fresh install.

Comment: @harrymc Good find. Voted to close as duplicate.